# Create Data Frame from IF Condition

Tags: r

I've look for this question; however no examples seem to be as primitive as I need.

I need to be able to create a data frame that contains only the true values from an IF condition.. for example:

```
if(sampleDF$column[1]== 1){
  newDF(sampleDF)
}
```

In this example newDF should contain those rows from sampleDF where column has a value of 1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a logical vector to index a data.frame. So just pass your criteria in like `sampleDF[your_conditions_here, ]`

Comment: where you say "[your_conditions_here,]" would that be the entire IF statement?

Comment: Play around with it a bit and see what works. I also suggest playing around with just the conditions themselves. So in the console see what `sampleDF$column[1]` evaluates to. See what `sampleDF$column[1] == 1` evaluates to.

Comment: I have.. that only produces a true / false value.
I'm looking to pass in the entire row based of off that value to the new data frame.

Comment: Which should make sense right? What happens if you don't only grab the first element from the column?

Comment: sampleDF$column[1] - displays the value of that index (
sampleDF$column==1 vector TRUE / FALSE.  Displays the entire data frames true / false value for that column

Comment: So now think about how you can use that along with the fact that you can index a data.frame using a logical vector